# Stream Mediaplayer from URL then pass to another activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I created a loading activity, which shows a loading GIF while fetching MP3 file from my own URL. When the media player is ready , i put it into my singleton and then go to the the intent (so that i can use that MP3 on this new activity).

The thing is this rarely goes well and usually idle for long (both onListener are not even called)

Please help.

```
package com.example.songguessapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent; import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.MediaPlayer; import android.os.Bundle; import
android.util.Log; import android.view.View; import
android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SongGame game;
    static public MediaPlayer mpTemp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);


        game = SongGame.getInstance();
        String songCode = String.valueOf(game.getRound() + 1);
        String url = "https://mp3stream.herokuapp.com/code=song" + songCode ;

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                 new AudioAttributes
                         .Builder()
                         .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                         .build());
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d("1001","Song downloaded");
                toGameScreen(mp)
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                Log.d("1002","Error here");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    public void toGameScreen(MediaPlayer mp) {
        SongGame.getInstance().setMediaPlayer(mp);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
   }
 }
```

**EDITED** here is my edited version (finally worked), but i dont know how the thread issue is related to my previous work.

```
package com.example.songguessapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoadingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SongGame game;
     public MediaPlayer mpTemp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);


//        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
//        mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
//                new AudioAttributes
//                        .Builder()
//                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
//                        .build());
//        try {
//            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
//
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//            Toast.makeText(this,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        }
//        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
//
//        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
//                toGameScreen(mp);
//
//            }
//        });
//
//        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
//
//                return false;
//            }
//        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               game = SongGame.getInstance();
               String songCode = String.valueOf(game.getRound() + 1);
               String url = "https://mp3stream.herokuapp.com/code=song" + songCode ;

                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(
                        new AudioAttributes
                                .Builder()
                                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                                .build());
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 toGameScreen(mediaPlayer)




        }).start();
    }



    public void toGameScreen(MediaPlayer mp) {
        SongGame.getInstance().setMediaPlayer(mp);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors printed out to console?

Comment: Hi Jakir, no errors are printed on console.

Answer (score 0):

I am not experienced with media playback but your solution using a thread reminded me that in Android you **MUST ALWAYS** try to **NOT** block the **UI thread**. From this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer the main docs:

> Using MediaPlayer can be straightforward in principle. However, it's
>   important to keep in mind that a few more things are necessary to
>   integrate it correctly with a typical Android application. For
>   example, the call to prepare() can take a long time to execute,
>   because it might involve fetching and decoding media data. So, as is
>   the case with any method that may take long to execute, you
>   should never call it from your application's UI thread.  . . . To
>   avoid hanging your UI thread, spawn another thread to prepare
>   the MediaPlayer and notify the main thread when done.

So my suggestion would be to try running the playback on a foreground service https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services